# How can I expand lines hidden by "[+]" in the output of `docker-compose build`?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

In the terminal window, some of Docker Compose output collapses behind a "[+]" hiding the messages I need to see.  How do I reveal these lines or prevent the collapsing in the first place?

```
PS aws_linux_2>docker-compose build al
[+] Building 1.0s (16/16) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                               0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(They're not really "collapsed"- more like the line in the terminal emulator is being re-written. See also [ANSI Escape Codes - CSI sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences)).

See [the `--progress` option of `docker-compose build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_build/#options). Try setting it to `plain`, like `docker-compose build --progress=plain al` or `docker-compose build --progress plain al`.